# How do you use a lambda expresion with complex math in java

Tags: java, math, lambda

hello i a trying to compare to values after i apply a lambda experrsion to them im trying to compare a location of a player and another to see the distance between them and im having trouble with lambdas

```java
public class mathprob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    Location loc = player.getlocation();
    Location newloc = player.getlocation();

    (loc, newloc) -> Math.pow((loc.getX()-newloc.getX()), 2) + 
        Math.pow(loc.getY()-newloc.getY(), 2)+Math.pow(loc.getZ()- 
        newloc.getZ(), 
    2));

}
```

i keep getting a error because the lambda is incorrect i dont know how to use a lambda in this situation and then comparing the two values to each other (loc, newloc) the two values or two points P1(loc.getX(), loc,getY(), loc.getZ()) and P2(newloc.getX(), newloc.getY(), newloc.getZ()) i wanna compare the x and the y and the z of each point to see the number gap between them

Comment: lambdas and 'complex math' are utterly unrelated. Just.. stop writing `->`.

Comment: You have written a lambda expression as the sole thing in a statement. That's sort of like writing "`5;`", which doesn't make much sense at all. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Nothing here seems to want or need lambdas.

Comment: N.B. that you also probably should have `sqrt` as the outside function.

Comment: A lambda expression implements a method in an interface. So first you need a method in an interface. From the code in your question, it looks like your lambda expression is implementing a method that has two parameters, both of type `Location` and returns a `double`. So what method, of what interface, is your lambda expression supposed to implement?

Comment: While you *could* solve this using lambdas, IMO they are not the right tool to use here.  You want either a inline (ordinary) expression, or maybe an (ordinary) method.

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are just a way to create a type for a function.  Keep in mind that a function has no "values" and hasn't been executed yet.

You can apply any Lambda to a set of values by calling it's `apply` method.  It will then take the inputs (parameters to apply) and return the value as the result.  A Lambda for a function that looks like this

```
(Coordinate x) -> { return new Distance(Math.sqrt(x.x * x.x + x.y * x.y)) }
```

would return the distance to the origin for a `Coordinate` assuming a Coordinate looked a little like

```
public class Coordinate {
   public double x;
   public double y;
}
```

and Distance looked a bit like like

```
public class Distance {

   public Distance(double value) {
      ... whatever the implementation is ...
   }

}
```

This function has a type conversion in it, it takes a `Coordinate` and returns a `Distance`.  This means it fits the java "interface" of

```
Function<Coordinate, Distance>
```

and just by writing this Lambda

```
(Coordinate x) -> { return new Distance(Math.sqrt(x.x * x.x + x.y * x.y)) }
```

The Java compiler will generate some unnamed class of type `Function<Coordinate, Distance>` and instantiate an instance (create an object the class) to use in the context of the location of the Lambda.

Now if that lambda is within a method of a stream, such that the stream's parameter types are compatible, the stream will (in some manner) call `apply` on each value the stream is handling.  Those values come from a `Supplier` which is basically an object that has a `T get()` method.

1. Stream calls the Supplier's `get()` method.
2. Stream has a method `.forEach( ... )` containing a lambda that consumes the `get()` type.
3. Stream applies the value of `get()` to the lambda in `forEach()` by passing it into `apply(value)`.
4. Stream collects the result of `apply(value)`
5. Stream returns from the `.forEach(...)` method a new stream with values typed to match the return value of the lambda in the `forEach()` method.
6. Eventually, these values are passed into a `Collector` method which combines values into some sort of buffer.  Sometimes a List, sometimes a single value.

Conveniences exist for various ways of simplifying the collectors.  Conveniences exist for generating values without coding suppliers.
The lambda syntax itself is a convenience for not having to write an implementation of one of the "xxxFunction" interfaces, create an object of it, and pass it into the stream.
Predicates are what they call Functions that return boolean values.  There are even more convenience functions that work with predicates.

So, if you don't have a collection of data points to process, you probably shouldn't be using lambdas.  If you do have a collection of data points to process, then keep in mind that streams and lambdas provide a new not-quite-like-a-loop way of processing them.  They are guaranteed to be applied to all values, but the order of their application is not necessarily in the strong ordering that a traditional loop would apply.  With the right options, you can effectively split the input into multiple chunks (spliterator vs iterator) and process the data in parallel.

Now that you have a quick overview of Lambdas, Streams, and the Functional interfaces, you can see that

```
(loc, newloc) -> Math.pow((loc.getX()-newloc.getX()), 2) + 
 Math.pow(loc.getY()-newloc.getY(), 2)+Math.pow(loc.getZ()-newloc.getZ(), 
 2));
```

wouldn't "do" anything, because at best it describes this

```
public class MyFunction implements Function<Location, Location, Double> {
    Double apply(Location first, Location second) {
       return Math.pow((first.getX()-second.getX()), 2)
              + Math.pow(first.getY()-second.getY(), 2)
              + Math.pow(first.getZ()-second.getZ(), 2)
    }
}

MyFunction myFunc = new MyFunction();
```

Which has the following problem"

- It's a coding error as it's only creating the facility to transform locations, and never using it.

Using the facility would look like

```
double result = myFunc.apply(loc, newloc);
```

Now, the very astute readers will mention auto-boxing, but in reality the compiler would choose the `ToDoubleBiFunction` type, probably side-stepping some of the possible auto-boxing issues.  I just didn't want to write the example up in the non-generic manner, as again, the primitive functional types are a convenience (and optimization) of the general "all object" description above.

Comment: Sorry for the length, but there was a lot of ground to cover, and this is a pretty "terse" exposure to Lambdas for a person who's really having difficulty seeing the whole picture.

Comment: Great answer. Not sure if it will really help this OP, so lets hope his question doesn't collect more downvotes and gets deleted. Not a good sign though that the OP just walks aways and doesnt respond to any of the comments or answers.

Comment: @GhostCat We'l see.  Maybe the OP walked away because without the high-level overview, trying to use Lambdas is rather confusing.  I hope this gives the OP the overview needed for a lot of the other excellent comments to make sense.

Comment: Given the comment the OP gave on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68611605/1531124 ... I am not very optimistic.

Comment: @GhostCat that question was a rushed question and i just wanted to know the meaning of all the pins i was working in a project and asked that question to not have to research on every pin.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are used to generate anonymous functions. They can be used where a `@FunctionalInterface` is expected.

Read more about them here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

If you'd like your code to work you can assign your lambda to a BiFunction variable and then execute it passing in the loc and newloc.

```
public class mathprob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Location _loc = player.getlocation();
        Location _newloc = player.getlocation();

        BiFunction<Location, Location, Double> lambdaExpression = (loc, newloc) ->  {
           return Math.pow((loc.getX()-newloc.getX()), 2) +
              Math.pow(loc.getY()-newloc.getY(), 2)+Math.pow(loc.getZ()-newloc.getZ(),
              2);
        };

        double result = lambdaExpression.apply(_loc, _newloc);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how the equivalent method declaration would look like instead of using a lambda:

```
public class mathprob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Location loc = player.getlocation();
        Location newloc = player.getlocation();
        double result = calculate(loc, newloc);
    }
    

    public static double calculate(Location loc, Location newloc) {     
        return
            Math.pow((loc.getX() - newloc.getX()), 2) + 
            Math.pow(loc.getY() - newloc.getY(), 2) + 
            Math.pow(loc.getZ() - newloc.getZ(), 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi lets say i wanted to do the same thing with 2 points, ```P1(newloc.getX(), newloc.getY(), newloc.getZ())``` and ```P2(loc.getX(), loc.getY() loc.getZ())``` and then i wanted to find the distance between them i wanted to find the distance or the number gap between loc.getX() and newloc.getX() using lambda expressions is it the same context?

Comment: @NayefAlhajraf - You need update your question to explain clearly what you are trying to do with lambdas.

Comment: Hey @NayefAlhajraf I was answering your question about how to use lambda expressions. I'm not sure of your mathematical intentions. I updated my answer to show you the equivalent method definition for clarity. Hopefully this will help you gain a clearer understanding.

Comment: @Stephen C i listened to your comment and have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [14.5. Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) from JLS.

`value;`

is not a valid statement, as

`"text";` or `5;` are not.

Lambda Expression is a *value*, which constitutes an anonymous method, and which can be assigned to the variable (of Functional Interface type) or can be passed into method, as an ordinary argument value.

```java
public void someMethod() {

    5; //does not compile, as this is not a statement.

    int x = 5; //compiles, as this is a statement.

    //Similarly,
    () -> System.out.println("Hi"); //does not compile, as this is not a statement

    Runnable r1 = () -> System.out.println("Hi"); //compiles, as this is a statement

}
```